# Click is not working on 'Import From' menu' to get the second menu dynamically and then click on 'Device...' Option

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom

I am facing a big issue and unable to resolve. Working whole day on it.

the Issue is :: with-respect-to below 'menu' in the picture. This is dynamic menu. When I hover on File menu from the top. this menu shown but now the child is rendered. SO for that I  hover the 'import from' menu the child menu appears and I just want to click the 'device...' menu before its dynamically disappear.

To acheive that i wrote below code. But its not working. Please help. If someone understand what is going wrong.

code.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.geItem');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].innerHTML === 'File') {
      // Create a new click event
      var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        view: window
      });
      (elements[i] as any).click();
      
      setTimeout(() => {
        var menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('td.mxPopupMenuItem[align="left"]');
        var importFromMenu;
        for (var j = 0; j < menuItems.length; j++) {
          var menuItem = menuItems[j];
          if (menuItem.textContent.trim() === "Import from") {
            importFromMenu = menuItem;
            console.log('import from:');
            console.log(importFromMenu);
            (importFromMenu as any).click()
            break;
          }
        }
      }, 2000);
      break; // If you only want to click on the first matching element, you can add this break statement
    }
  }
```

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="mxPopupMenu geMenubarMenu" style="display: inline; z-index: 10006; left: 146.969px; top: 345.906px; overflow: hidden auto; max-height: 1300px;">
     <table class="mxPopupMenu">
          <tbody>
               <tr class="mxPopupMenuItem">
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuIcon"></td>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuItem" align="left">Open from</td>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuItem" style="padding-right: 6px; text-align: right;"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCQAJAIAAAP///zMzMyH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAJAAkAAAIPhI8WebHsHopSOVgb26AAADs=" /></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuIcon" style="padding: 0px;"></td>
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding: 0px;"><hr size="1" /></td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="mxPopupMenuItem">
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuIcon"></td>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuItem" align="left">Save</td>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuItem" style="padding-right: 6px; text-align: right;"><span style="color: gray;">Ctrl+S</span></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuIcon" style="padding: 0px;"></td>
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding: 0px;"><hr size="1" /></td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="mxPopupMenuItem">
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuIcon"></td>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuItem" align="left">Rename...</td>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuItem" style="padding-right: 6px; text-align: right;"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuIcon" style="padding: 0px;"></td>
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding: 0px;"><hr size="1" /></td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="mxPopupMenuItem">
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuIcon"></td>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuItem" align="left">Import from</td>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuItem" style="padding-right: 6px; text-align: right;"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCQAJAIAAAP///zMzMyH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAJAAkAAAIPhI8WebHsHopSOVgb26AAADs=" /></td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="mxPopupMenuItem">
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuIcon"></td>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuItem" align="left">Export as</td>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuItem" style="padding-right: 6px; text-align: right;"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCQAJAIAAAP///zMzMyH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAJAAkAAAIPhI8WebHsHopSOVgb26AAADs=" /></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuIcon" style="padding: 0px;"></td>
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding: 0px;"><hr size="1" /></td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="mxPopupMenuItem">
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuIcon"></td>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuItem" align="left">Embed</td>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuItem" style="padding-right: 6px; text-align: right;"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCQAJAIAAAP///zMzMyH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAJAAkAAAIPhI8WebHsHopSOVgb26AAADs=" /></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuIcon" style="padding: 0px;"></td>
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding: 0px;"><hr size="1" /></td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="mxPopupMenuItem">
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuIcon"></td>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuItem" align="left">New Library</td>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuItem" style="padding-right: 6px; text-align: right;"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCQAJAIAAAP///zMzMyH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAJAAkAAAIPhI8WebHsHopSOVgb26AAADs=" /></td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="mxPopupMenuItem">
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuIcon"></td>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuItem" align="left">Open Library from</td>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuItem" style="padding-right: 6px; text-align: right;"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCQAJAIAAAP///zMzMyH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAJAAkAAAIPhI8WebHsHopSOVgb26AAADs=" /></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuIcon" style="padding: 0px;"></td>
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding: 0px;"><hr size="1" /></td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="mxPopupMenuItem">
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuIcon"></td>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuItem" align="left">Properties...</td>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuItem" style="padding-right: 6px; text-align: right;"></td>
               </tr>
          </tbody>
     </table>
</div>

<div class="mxPopupMenu" style="position: absolute; display: inline; z-index: 10006; left: 385px; top: 537px; overflow: hidden auto; max-height: 1186px;">
     <table class="mxPopupMenu">
          <tbody>
               <tr class="mxPopupMenuItem">
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuIcon"></td>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuItem" align="left">Device...</td>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuItem" style="padding-right: 6px; text-align: right;"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuIcon" style="padding: 0px;"></td>
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding: 0px;"><hr size="1" /></td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="mxPopupMenuItem">
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuIcon"></td>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuItem" align="left">Dwp Library</td>
                    <td class="mxPopupMenuItem" style="padding-right: 6px; text-align: right;"></td>
               </tr>
          </tbody>
     </table>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show us the html too?

Comment: @Turbo19973 yes

Comment: but remener.. HTML is dynamically generated... when i click on File menu.